# Kalman Filter/Majvik Filter

Tags: filter, angle, kalman-filter

I have an accelerometer sensor and a gyroscope sensor, both three-axis. I would have to somehow calculate the roll/pitch angles in dynamics according to the accelerometer and gyroscope readings, as well as the yaw angle according to the gyroscope readings (in the future I will add a magnetometer for correction).

To solve this problem, I decided to use the Kalman filter. Data from sensors is read by acceleration, gyroscope = **get_data()**, a list of 6 values is returned. Next, I consider the change of angles according to the data from the gyroscope **delta_gyro_angle(gyroscope, delta_time)**. Then I calculate the angles using the accelerometer **compute_roll_pitch(acceleration)**. After that, I try to combine them through the Kalman filter **filter_angles(accel_angles, gyro_delta s, gyro_noise, accel_noise)**. But I have a feeling that my implementation of the kalman filter ignores the change of angles by gyroscope. I also have problems with rare, but large outliers of data from the accelerometer (for example, a 1.5-fold jump in a static state). In addition, I have problems when the pitch angle is close to 90 degrees. There are also problems with the angle +-180.

How can I solve these problems?

In short, I want to get angles based on the readings of the accelerometer and gyroscope while in motion, and most likely non-linear. I want to use this data in my radio-controlled toy boat.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import math
 
def normalize(vector):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(vector)
    if norm == 0:
        return vector
    return vector / norm
 
def compute_roll_pitch(acceleration):
    # Normalize acceleration
    acceleration = normalize(acceleration)
    
    # Calculate pitch angle (pitch) and roll angle (roll)
    pitch = math.asin(-acceleration[0])
    roll = math.atan2(acceleration[1], acceleration[2])
 
    # Convert angles from radians to degrees
    pitch_degrees = math.degrees(pitch)
    roll_degrees = math.degrees(roll)
 
    return roll_degrees, pitch_degrees
 
class KalmanFilter:
    def __init__(self, initial_angles, gyro_noise, accel_noise):
        # Initialization of matrices and filter parameters
        self.angle_estimate = np.array(initial_angles)  # Initial estimation of angles
        self.angle_covariance = np.identity(3)  # Initial covariance of angles
        self.gyro_noise = gyro_noise
        self.accel_noise = accel_noise
 
    def update(self, gyro_deltas, accel_angles):
        # Predicting the next filter state
        predicted_angle = self.angle_estimate + gyro_deltas
        predicted_covariance = self.angle_covariance + self.gyro_noise
 
        # Calculation of the correction coefficient (Kalman coefficient)
        kalman_gain = np.dot(predicted_covariance, np.linalg.inv(predicted_covariance + self.accel_noise))
 
        # Updating the angle estimation based on the accelerometer readings
        self.angle_estimate = predicted_angle + np.dot(kalman_gain, (accel_angles - predicted_angle))
        self.angle_covariance = np.dot((np.identity(3) - kalman_gain), predicted_covariance)
 
        return self.angle_estimate.tolist()
 
def filter_angles(accel_angles, gyro_deltas, gyro_noise, accel_noise):
    # Creating a Kalman filter object
    kalman_filter = KalmanFilter(accel_angles, gyro_noise, accel_noise)
 
    # Angle filtering using gyroscope and accelerometer data
    filtered_angles = [accel_angles]
    for delta in gyro_deltas:
        filtered_angle = kalman_filter.update(delta, accel_angles)
        filtered_angles.append(filtered_angle)
 
    return filtered_angles[-1]


roll, pitch, yaw = 0, 0, 0
time_output = time.time() 
start_time = time.time() 
 
total_roll = [] # Roll history
total_pitch = [] # Pitch history
total_data = [] # History of data from accelerometer and gyroscope
 
while True:
    delta_time = time.time() - start_time # Time between iterations
    start_time = time.time()
    
    acceleration, gyroscope = get_data() # Getting data from accelerometer and gyroscope
    
    delta_roll, delta_pitch, delta_yaw = delta_gyro_angle(gyroscope, delta_time) # Calculation of angle changes by gyroscope
    roll_accel, pitch_accel = compute_roll_pitch(acceleration) # Calculating angles by accelerometer
    yaw_accel = yaw # add a magnetometer in future.
       
    accel_angles = [roll_accel, pitch_accel, yaw_accel]  # Accelerometer-based angles (roll, pitch, yaw)
    gyro_deltas = [delta_roll, delta_pitch, delta_yaw]  # Angular gyroscope changes (roll delta, pitch delta, yaw delta)
    gyro_noise = np.identity(3) * 0.00001  # Gyroscope noise matrix
    accel_noise = np.identity(3) * 0.001  # Accelerometer noise matrix
 
    roll, pitch, yew = filter_angles(accel_angles, gyro_deltas, gyro_noise, accel_noise)
 
    
    if time.time() - time_output > 0.01:
        time_output = time.time()
        padding = ' ' * 100
        print(f"{yaw}, {pitch}, {roll}{padding}\r", end="")   
 
    total_roll.append(roll) 
    total_pitch.append(pitch)
    total_data.append([acceleration, gyroscope])
```

Comment: To measure the accuracy of the angles that my program calculates, I use a special setup that measures the angle very accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your approach of updating with gyro measurement, and doing a correction to that using accelerometer measurement is the right approach here. A typical Kalman filter setup uses gyro for attitude prediction, and accelerometer for position prediction. Then uses external sensors such as GNSS as a correction.

If you are going to use this system on a boat, which is a high dynamic system, your accelerometers are going to detect impacts and high-acceleration measurements as body-accelerations, and going to give you wrong angle measurements. This is also will be true for gyro measurements.

I think a better approach here would be to use something like a complimentary filter. See an example implementation [here](https://ahrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters/complementary.html).

Comment: If I have problems with the angle +-180, then should I use quaternions? When calculating angles close to 180 degrees, I have big jumps due to the transition through zero, if you follow the formulas that you wrote.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by problem with angle +-180, but I assume it is the pi-wrap. I think you can use Euler angles as long as you do the pi-wrap before being used in a filter. 

Mathematically, the correct way is to use rotation matrices (SO(3)), the next best option is quaternions, and the last option is Euler. Check Table 1 [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6339217/).

Comment: I mean the problem with the angle +-180 is that if now the angle on the accelerometer is +179.9, and with a small change in the angle the next one turns out to be -179.9, then the angles run through zero. For example: +179.9, +120, +30, 0, -30, -120, -179.9. Intermediate false values are obtained.

Comment: I also had an idea that it is possible to make the alpha parameter in a complementary filter dynamically changing according to the gyroxope readings. For example, if the angular velocities are large according to the gyroscope, then we increase the alpha parameter. If the gyroscope speeds near zero, then the alpha parameter is reduced to zero. Will this increase the accuracy of calculations?

Comment: I also have a problem with a pitch angle of 90 degrees. Since it is impossible to calculate the roll angle at such an angle.

Comment: I also thought, is it not necessary to use a rotation matrix when calculating angles using gyroscope data?

Comment: I think you may need to figure out the basics of attitude estimation before trying to tackle the problem. The filters try to "filter out" noise. So when it gets 179.9 at -179.9, it is going to think it is noise. So doing "+179.9, +120, +30, 0, -30, -120, -179.9" is the intended behavior, not a wrong calculation. You need to implement your own pi-wrap before or after running the filter. If you have know idea what I am talking about, may be you should try to use an open-source implementation instead of making your own.

Comment: Can you advise me on an open source python implementation?

Comment: The URL in my original reply is a Python-based open-source implementation of a collection of attitude estimators.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my mistakes and it works. But I have a problem with the speed of calculations. If I change the alpha value to 0.992, then the speed of calculating angles will be very small. The calculated angles are 1.5-2 seconds behind the actual position. How can this be fixed? If I decrease the alpha value, then the angles are calculated quickly, but at high accelerations the angles become unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed it by analogy with the site that you threw off. I don't really like the operation of this device with fluctuations. Because the angles jump strongly. I have an idea to make the alpha parameter dynamic, change it according to the gyroscope and accelerometer data. But so far I don't understand how to do it better.

```
import math
import serial
import time
import numpy as np

def calculate_angles_accel(accel):
    a_x, a_y, a_z = accel
    
    teta_x = math.atan2(a_y, a_z)
    teta_y = math.atan2(-a_x, (a_y ** 2 + a_z ** 2) ** .5)
    teta_z = 0
    
    return [teta_x, teta_y, teta_z]

def calculate_angles_magnetometer(magnet, angles_accel):
    m_x, m_y, m_z = magnet
    teta_x, teta_y, teta_z = angles_accel
    
    b_x = m_x * math.cos(teta_x) + m_y * math.sin(teta_x) * sin(teta_y) + m_z * math.sin(teta_x) * math.cos(teta_y)
    b_y = m_y * math.cos(teta_y) - m_z * math.sin(teta_y)
    b_z = -m_x * math.sin(teta_x) + m_y * math.cos(teta_x) * math.sin(teta_y) + m_z * math.cos(teta_x) * math.cos(teta_y)
    
    teta_z = math.atan2(-b_y, b_x)
    return [teta_x, teta_y, teta_z]

def calculate_angles_gyro(gyro, last_angles, delta_time):
    w_x, w_y, w_z = gyro
    teta_x, teta_y, teta_z = last_angles
    
    new_teta_x = teta_x + w_x * delta_time
    new_teta_y = teta_y + w_y * delta_time
    new_teta_z = teta_z + w_z * delta_time
    
    return [new_teta_x, new_teta_y, new_teta_z]

def complementary_filter(accel, gyro, last_angles, delta_time, alpha=0.2, magnet=[]):
    angles_accel = calculate_angles_accel(accel)
    
    if len(magnet) == 3: # if magnetometer turned on
        angles_accel = calculate_angles_accel(magnet, angles_accel)
    
    angles_gyro = calculate_angles_gyro(gyro, last_angles, delta_time)
    
    teta_x = alpha * angles_gyro[0] + (1 - alpha) * angles_accel[0]
    teta_y = alpha * angles_gyro[1] + (1 - alpha) * angles_accel[1]
    teta_z = alpha * angles_gyro[2] + (1 - alpha) * angles_accel[2]
    
    return [teta_x, teta_y, teta_z]

def convert_radians_to_degrees(angles):
    for i in range(len(angles)):
        angles[i] = round(math.degrees(angles[i]), 2)
    return angles

# Closing a port if it is open
try:
    ser.close()  
except:
    pass

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 1000000) 

roll, pitch, yaw = 0, 0, 0
flag_0 = True

time_output = time.time()
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    delta_time = time.time() - start_time # Time between iterations
    start_time = time.time()
    
    acceleration, gyroscope = get_data() # Getting data from accelerometer and gyroscope
    
    if flag_0: # Setting the initial angles
        flag_0 = False
        roll, pitch, yaw = calculate_angles_accel(acceleration)
        continue
        # Add magnetometer if it necessary
    
    roll, pitch, yaw = complementary_filter(acceleration, gyroscope, [roll, pitch, yaw], delta_time) # Calculation of angles by a complementary filter
    
    roll_deg, pitch_deg, yaw_deg = convert_radians_to_degrees([roll, pitch, yaw]) # Converting angles from radians to degrees
    
    if time.time() - time_output > 0.01:
        time_output = time.time()
        padding = ' ' * 100
        print(f"{roll_deg}, {pitch_deg}, {yaw_deg}{padding}\r", end="")
```